# How to evaluate a definite integral involving the product of two sines?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> The input signal for a given electronic circuit is a function of time $V_{in}(t)$. The output signal is given by 
>   $$V_{out}(t) = \int_0^t \sin(t-s) V_{in}(s)\,ds$$
>
> Find $V_{out}(t)$ if $V_{in}(t) = \sin(at)$ where $a > 0$ is some constant.

Please help with this answer, I have now learned that this can be simplified into 
1/2(cos(t-(a+1)s)-cos(t+(a-1)s)) but I do not know how to further continue the integration of this.

Comment: In other words we have $$\int_0^t\sin(t-s)\sin(as)ds$$?  Have you expanded $\sin(t-s)$ using the angle sum formula for $\sin$?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that the integral is taken from 0 to t

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the product to sum identity $\sin A \sin B = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\right]$.

This gives you $\sin(t-s)\sin(as) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\cos(t-(a+1)s)-\cos(t+(a-1)s)\right]$.

This should be easy to integrate.

Comment: I am still a bit stuck on what to do once I am at that point in order to integrate